# Record data to a database using AJAX

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, html, ajax

I need to use AJAX to save user input comments instantly to the database.
This is the comment box.

```
<div class="comment">
        <form action="comment.php">
        <textarea cols="35" name="comments"> Give us comment </textarea>
        <input type="button" value="comment" onclick="ajaxFunction()">
        </form>                 
 </div>
```

This is the php code

```
<?php

$link = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("continental_tourism");

$comments = $_POST['comments'];

if($comments == "")
echo "Please type your comment";
else
{
$query = "insert into comment(comment) values('$comments') ";
mysql_query($query);
} 
return;
?>
```

I need to know how this should be changed. 
Thank You

Comment: I think seeing `ajaxFunction()` will be necessary. Also, if you want people to drop tables for you, just ask. SQL injection shouldn't be this easy. Please look into prepared statements.

Comment: you need to send the data in ajaxfunction()

Comment: can you include the code for ajaxFunction()? In general, you can take a look at a framework like prototype or jQuery.

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)?

Comment: @David Z I don't did the ajaxFunction. Thats what i need here :)

Comment: Ah gotcha, it wasn't very clear from the post. There's an answer below that seems to answer it fairly well if you're using jQuery (which I do recommend)

Comment: @Bracketworks But I love [little bobby tables](http://xkcd.com/327/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would chnage your HTML like this

```
<textarea cols="35" id="comments"> Give us comment </textarea>
<input type="button" value="comment" id="btnSave" />
```

And the script

```
$(function(){
 $("#btnSave").click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $.post("yourphpfile.php", { comments : $("#comments").val() } ,function(data){
     alert(data);
  });  
 }); 
});
```

The above script will send an ajax request to yourphpfile.php with the value present in the textarea with id comment. Then once it gets some data back from the server page. it justs alerts it ( you may show this in a seperate div if you want ). You should echo the response from your php file after saving the data to database.

As bracketworks already mentioned, you should be careful about SQL injections while saving data which is being read from the querystring value. do proper sanitization before putting it in a query. Sorry i am not a php guy. so not sure how to do that.

**Don't forget to include the jQuery library to your page**.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

You may use firebug console for debugging your script error if you run into any.

Comment: @jeroen: Sure. :) I will add that to the answer.

Comment: You can do something simple like running $escaped_value = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['comment']); to escape

Comment: There are many different frameworks for doing this, so you definitely have your pick (i.e. http://www.prototypejs.org/api/form/request). However, I'd definitely use one of those versus rolling your own because there are definitely hidden gotchas across different browsers.

Comment: @jeroen: I forgot about preventing the default behavior. I updated my answeer. Thanks for bringing it up.` preventDefault` is preferred over `return false`;

Comment: Normally I would also suggest changing jQueryUI to jQuery but I don't like these `give me the codez` questions so I won't ;)

Comment: @jeroen: Ah ! It was my mistake. I copied the wrong reference :( Thanks for looking into it. You rock :) . I updated.